# jquery function not alerting string

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

```
$("#radio5").click(function() 
{
    document.getElementById("ti").style.display="table";
        $.ajax
        ({
            type:"GET",
            url:"inst.php",
            dataType:"xml",
            success: xmlInstructor  
        });
});


function xmlInstructor(xml)
{

    $(xml).find('Instructor').each(function()
    {

     instructorName = $(this).find('InstructorName').text();

        $("#ti").append("<tr><td>"+"<input type='button' id='instructorButton'  onclick='i_click("+instructorName+")' value='ADD' />"+"</td><td>"+instructorName+"</td></tr>");
    });         
}
```

Code works fine until here. but I want to alert instructorName on i_click function which i am not able to get. If i pass integer it works but but not with string.

```
 function i_click(instructorName)
{
    alert(instructorName);
    }
```

Not able to alert instructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because the string parameter is not surrounding with quotes

Replace this

```
<input type='button' id='instructorButton' 
                         onclick='i_click("+instructorName+")' value='ADD' />
```

With

```
<input type=\"button\" id=\"instructorButton\" 
       onclick=\"i_click('" +instructorName +"')\" value=\"ADD\" />
```

This will fix your problem.